# Get a weekly average on day macro is run

Tags: excel, vba

Busy with going through a macro course. What would be the best way to deal with a problem like this:

a) On a daily basis a daily value is inserted into the data sheet

b) The week runs from Monday to Sunday

c) At any given moment, if the
macro is run, a weekly average needs to be outputted on a separate
sheet. So if today is Thursday, the average from Mon-Wed needs to be
pulled.

d) I've attached an example data set, but I will expand it
to the real data later when I figure out which tools will be
appropriate.

[image]

Comment: One approach (of many) is to locate yesterday's date in column A. Loop backwards (while summing the corresponding cell in column B and perhaps keeing a counter of days) until you hit a Monday. Then divide the sum by the days counter. Make sure you don't divide by zero. Write some code and update your question if you run into problems. Please include the code (or the part that's causing the problem). All the best

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this as well as I need to understand looping (already started using the step -1, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use the following VBA Code, which I believe it will suit you

It will bring to you on another Sheet the average for the dates within the current week. I updated with month function as you asked

```
Sub Test()
Dim LR As Integer

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("E1").Value = "=Weeknum(Today())"
Range("F1").Value = "=Month(Today())"

For i = 1 To LR
    Range("C" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Range("A" & i))
    Range("D" & i).Formula = "=Month(A" & i & ")"
Next i

Worksheets("Planilha2").Range("A1").Value = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C:C"), Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("E1").Value, Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B:B"))
Worksheets("Planilha2").Range("B1").Value = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("D:D"), Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("F1").Value, Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("B:B"))

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems right from your code, share the error code in order to see what went wrong in your case. The accomplish to the same logic for month, I updated the answer, just take a look

Comment: The `Month` Function is not available on `Worksheets.Function`, that why I have used another approach for it, check the link to see all the formuls available on `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/list-of-worksheet-functions-available-to-visual-basic`

Comment: Yes, I went with pivot tables for the month. Thanks for the reply. I added a heading row, but I'm getting an error on this line because I changed the range (the first row of the data sheet is the column headings) `Worksheets("Consolidation report").Range("D66").Value = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C"), Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B"))`

Comment: The error is 1004 Unable to get the AverageIf property of worksheetfunction class

Comment: Can you share with the print screen of your worksheet after you ran the vba code?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to use adodb. Header is MYDay, Quantity.

```
Sub exeSQLgetdata()
 
    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Fn As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim strSQL As String, sWsname As String
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim rngWeek As Range
    Dim st, et
    
    st = Timer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)  '<~~ data Sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) '<~~ Report Sheet
    
    sWsname = "[" & Ws.Name & "$]"
    
    Fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Database9.accdb"
    
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
 
    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    strSQL = "SELECT DATEPART('W', MYDay, 1) as WeekDay, AVG(Quantity) AS AVERAGE FROM " & sWsname & " GROUP BY DATEPART('W', MYDay,1) "
    
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn
    
    If Not Rs.EOF Then
        With toWs
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, i + 1) = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next i
            .UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
            .Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset Rs
            Set rngWeek = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            vDB = rngWeek
            For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
                vDB(i, 1) = Format(vDB(i, 1), "ddd", vbSunday)
            Next i
            rngWeek = vDB
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
    et = Timer
    
    Debug.Print "Get Data time : " & et - st & " seconds" 
End Sub
```

---

The above code is to average by weekday. The weekly average is as follows.

```
Sub exeSQLgetdata2()
 
    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Fn As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim strSQL As String, sWsname As String
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim rngWeek As Range
    Dim st, et
    
    st = Timer
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)  '<~~ data Sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) '<~~ Report Sheet
    
    sWsname = "[" & Ws.Name & "$]"
    
    Fn = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Database9.accdb"
    
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
 
    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    '2 : Monday to Sunday,  1: Sunday to Saturday
    strSQL = "SELECT DATEPART('WW', MYDay, 2) as WeekNum, AVG(Quantity) AS AVERAGE FROM " & sWsname & " GROUP BY DATEPART('WW', MYDay,2) "
    
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn
    
    If Not Rs.EOF Then
        With toWs
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, i + 1) = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next i
            .UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
            .Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset Rs
'            Set rngWeek = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
'            vDB = rngWeek
'            For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
'                vDB(i, 1) = Format(vDB(i, 1), "ddd", vbSunday)
'            Next i
'            rngWeek = vDB
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
    et = Timer
    
    Debug.Print "Get Data time : " & et - st & " seconds" 
End Sub
```

### Data Sheet sheets(1) image

[image]

### Resut Sheet sheets(2) image

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks a bit more complex as I just started out on VBA :) But Will have a look at it.